# Where does Ansible DSL get translated to either Powershell or Python?

Tags: ansible

When running Ansible scripts, where does the translation from Ansible DSL to Python(Linux) or Powershell(Windows) happen? I assume this is on the Ansible node, that is, where the Ansible command is executed?

**NOTE**: I'm NOT asking how to use Ansible itself, or how it works from a tooling perspective - I've been using it for years so I know how it works from that point of view.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "translation" happens in the Ansible task executor, which takes information about a module and pushes executable code to the target.

From [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/overview_architecture.html#modules):

> Ansible works by connecting to your nodes and pushing out scripts called “Ansible modules” to them.

So to answer your question:

> I assume this is on the Ansible node, that is, where the Ansible command is executed?

**yes**, this happens on the controller (the node where the `ansible` command is executed).

Based on the configuration of the controller, it knows where to look for modules. This is set by [the `ANSIBLE_LIBRARY`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-module-path) environment variable, or relevant section in the configuration file.

The [`_execute()`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/44dcfde9b84177e7dfede11ab287789c577b82b5/lib/ansible/executor/task_executor.py#L402) method of the Ansible task executor class is the place to look for how this happens.

In terms of what happens in detail, from what I can tell from the executor class, Ansible

1. Creates a task queue manager with the list of tasks (handling loops, etc)
2. for each task creates a task executor script based on the module type, pulling in all of the relevant context for that task (module variables, connection variables, magic variables)
3. Creates a connection to the remote target [see the `connection.py` library](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/connection.py)
4. Creates a pickle of the executable and writes it to the remote target (see [`write_to_file_descriptor()`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/connection.py#L47))

Part of the connection is determining the remote interpreter (python/powershell, etc) and the task executor takes care of ensuring that the remove interpreter for the module's execution environment is actually present (if, not, an error is raised).

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I was looking for (waves hand, LOL)